# How can I get Python 3.7 new dataclass field types?

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

Python 3.7 introduces new feature called data classes.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyClass:
    id: int = 0
    name: str = ''
```

When using type hints (annotation) in function parameters, you can easily get annotated types using inspect module. How can I get dataclass field types?

Comment: I would rather not to use private fields like that. Thanks anyway

Comment: It's not a private field. Also you just accepted an answer that does use "dunder" attributes.

Comment: BTW, the get_type_hints is recommended option than the use of `__annotations__`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyClass:
    id: int = 0
    name: str = '' 

myclass = MyClass()

myclass.__annotations__
>> {'id': int, 'name': str}
myclass.__dataclass_fields__
>> {'id': Field(name='id',type=<class 'int'>,default=0,default_factory=<dataclasses._MISSING_TYPE object at 0x0000000004EED668>,init=True,repr=True,hash=None,compare=True,metadata=mappingproxy({}),_field_type=_FIELD),
 'name': Field(name='name',type=<class 'str'>,default='',default_factory=<dataclasses._MISSING_TYPE object at 0x0000000004EED668>,init=True,repr=True,hash=None,compare=True,metadata=mappingproxy({}),_field_type=_FIELD)}
```

on a side note there is also:

```
myclass.__dataclass_params__
>>_DataclassParams(init=True,repr=True,eq=True,order=False,unsafe_hash=False,frozen=False)
```

Comment: I would rather not to use private fields like that. I need something like inspect module signature object.

Comment: Pay attention here, if you are not on 3.10 and use `from __future__ import annotations` the `type` field will be the `str` representation of the type, not the `type` itself.

Comment: @WolfgangPfnür Thank you for this comment, I've been bitten by this right now, wondering why were all the answers "incorrect".

Comment: @WolfgangPfnür Same here, lifesaver comment. This is an extremely nasty 'feature'.

Answer (score 120):

Inspecting `__annotations__` gives you the raw annotations, but those don't necessarily correspond to a dataclass's field types. Things like ClassVar and InitVar show up in `__annotations__`, even though they're not fields, and inherited fields don't show up.

Instead, call [`dataclasses.fields`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.fields) on the dataclass, and inspect the field objects:

```
field_types = {field.name: field.type for field in fields(MyClass)}
```

---

Neither `__annotations__` nor `fields` will resolve string annotations. If you want to resolve string annotations, the best way is probably [`typing.get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints). `get_type_hints` will include ClassVars and InitVars, so we use `fields` to filter those out:

```
resolved_hints = typing.get_type_hints(MyClass)
field_names = [field.name for field in fields(MyClass)]
resolved_field_types = {name: resolved_hints[name] for name in field_names}
```

Comment: To add to this, data classes support inheritance but `__annotations__ ` would not resolve fields from the parent class

Comment: What about getting also the default values of each field?

Comment: @EduardoPignatelli: `field.default` (which will be `dataclasses.MISSING` if there's no default).

Answer (score 5):

The [dataclasses.py](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) is **the module which provides decorator and functions for generating regular class methods** by using of the field annotations. Which means that after processing class, the user defined fields shall be formed using [PEP 526 Syntax of Variable annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#runtime-effects-of-type-annotations). The module annotations is accessible as `__annotations__`.

According to the [Runtime effects of type annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#runtime-effects-of-type-annotations) the annotated types is accessible via `__annotations__` attribute or by usage of the [typing.get_type_hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints), the last one the recommended.

Please see some code samples below:

```
from typing import Dict, ClassVar, get_type_hints
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Starship:
    hitpoints: int = 50


get_type_hints(Starship) // {'hitpoints': int}
Starship.__annotations__ // {'hitpoints': int}
dataclasses.__annotations__ // The annotations of the dataclasses module.
get_type_hints(get_type_hints)
```