# How to get class variables and type hints?

Tags: python, type-hinting

Assume I define a class with class level variables with type hints (e.g. something like the new python 3.7 `dataclasses`)

```
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int

    def parse_me(self):
        "what do I do here??"
```

How can I get the pairs of `(variable name, variable type)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get Python 3.7 new dataclass field types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51946571/how-can-i-get-python-3-7-new-dataclass-field-types)

Comment: Not a duplicate IMO. The other question is about the dataclasses for which there are different methods to extract annotations.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

[`typing.get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) is another method that doesn't involve accessing magic properties directly:

```
from typing import get_type_hints

class Person:
    name: str
    age: int

get_type_hints(Person)
# returns {'name': <class 'str'>, 'age': <class 'int'>}
```

Comment: It also renders "forward" annotations given as strings.

Answer (score 27):

These type hints are based on Python annotations. They are available as the `__annotations__` property. This goes for classes, as well as functions.

```
>>> class Person:
...     name: str
...     age: int
... 
>>> Person.__annotations__
{'name': <class 'str'>, 'age': <class 'int'>}
>>> def do(something: str) -> int:
...     ...
... 
>>> do.__annotations__
{'something': <class 'str'>, 'return': <class 'int'>}
```