# Extract type hints for object attributes in Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing

Can I extract type hints for object attributes in Python, at runtime?

For example, I want to extract the type of attribute `x` of class `C` in this example:

```py
class C:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x: int

# How can I extract "int" for attribute "x" of "C"?
```

I know this is possible for functions:

```py
from typing import get_type_hints


class C:

    def f(self, x: int):
        return x


print(get_type_hints(C.f)['x'].__name__)  # prints "int"
```

Comment: In your class `C`, `x` is "only" a local variable in `__init__`. Are you sure you didn't mean to put its definition outside of  `__init__`? In which case, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62723766/7212665) applies.

Comment: You are exactly right. I fixed my typo, and the question is indeed a duplicate - I marked it as such now. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: You can also use `dataclasses` in Python 3.x - this should make it easier to get the annotations for class attributes.