# How can I get the type annotation of a property of a class at runtime in Python

Tags: python, annotations, runtime

Look the code below:

```
class A():
    pass

class B():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.a: A = None

b = B()
assert (b.a.something == 'A') or (something(b) == 'A') or (something(b.a) == 'A')
```

***something*** is a method or function to call to get the answer desired.

I want to recover at runtime the type annotation for property **a** of the class **B**.

In other words, I want to get a return saying that **B.a** would be of type **A**.

There are any way to get it?

Thanks for help.

Comment: `b.a` is `None`, it's the value you assign in the initializer. The code you've posted will never have `A` as the type of `b.a` or any instance of `B.a`. Now, assuming that you assign an instance of `A` to `b.a`, you may get the type via the builtin function `type()`. Technically, you could also get the class name via `b.a.__class__`, but `type()` is preferable. Lastly, if you're merely testing that `b.a` is of type `A`, use `isinstance()`. To understand these builtins, type `help(type)` and `help(isinstance)` in the interactive prompt.

Comment: Does not care what is the type of the value of a. What I want is just the type described in the annotation. The type of the value of property b.a is irrelevant. I need to take the annotation.

Comment: If you redefine `B` with class-level type hints, `typing.get_type_hints()` will allow you to access the type annotations. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52838204/how-to-get-class-variables-and-type-hints

Comment: Thanks. It is interesting! Unfortunately, it does not work for the class style that is used inside the application. I really need that this feature can works at this example. I found, few minutes ago, the inspect module, that can return the source code to be parsed, but I guess that should have a better way to do it.