# Python: parameter type hint during run time

Tags: python, python-typing, python-dataclasses

Is it possible to check the parameter type hint at run time? I would like to use the Python dataclasses in a similar fashion to a Scala case class with `pureconfig` and HOCON config file. That is, I want to have some optional parameters but would need to check them in another class constructor. However, I dont see how I can get if a param is optional.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional

@dataclass
class Params:
    x: int
    y: int
    z: Optional[int] = None


params = Params(x=2, y=3)
```

Let's say I want to use the dataclass `Params` somewhere. If I check `z`, I will get a `NoneType`. Maybe I can by pass any errors if I know this by design.

```
# just some example code 
if z is None and z is not Optional (not sure if or how to check this):
    raise ValueError("z must be specified as an integer")

if z is None and z is optional:
    return x ** 2 + y ** 2
elif z is not None:
    return x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get class variables and type hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52838204/how-to-get-class-variables-and-type-hints)

Comment: @mkrieger1 thanks. I will take a look at this in detail tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

See below. The idea is to use `__post_init__` and check the annotations of `z`. Uncomment `#z: int` and see how it works.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional


@dataclass
class Params:
    x: int
    y: int
    z: Optional[int] = None
    #z: int

    def __post_init__(self):
        print('post init')
        if self.z is None:
            z_annotation = self.__annotations__['z']
            none_is_ok = False
            args = z_annotation.__dict__.get('__args__')
            if args is not None:
                for entry in args:
                    none_is_ok = entry == type(None)
                    if none_is_ok:
                        break
            if not none_is_ok:
                raise ValueError('z can not be None')


p: Params = Params(3, 5, None)
print(p)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at this answer the comment link in detail tomorrow to see which best services my purpose.

Comment: @dustin I think you should look at mypy (https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) as well. It will point to cases like those you mentioned